# Accessing Google Translator API

Tags: jsp, servlets, google-translate, servlet-3.0

I am using google translator API in order to translate a given text. language is selected through a dropdown and its value is sent to servlet. Through servlet translation method is called. but then I get the following error.

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Reque
st
{
  "code": 400,
  "errors": [
    {
      "domain": "global",
      "message": "Invalid Value",
      "reason": "invalid"
    }
  ],
  "message": "Invalid Value"
}
```

dropdown.jsp

```
 <form action="TextTranslation" method="post" class="form" role="form" >
        <div class="row">
            <div  id = "imageView" class="col-lg-8 center-block ">

         <div class="btn-group"> 
         <select name="country">

            <% 

          Map<String,String> langCode = x.getCountryList();
           for( Object key :langCode.keySet() )
           {%>


           <option value="<%=(String)key%>" > <%=langCode.get(key) %> </option>

              <% 

              System.out.println((String)key);
           }

           String name =  request.getParameter("country");


            %>



        </select>
           <input type="hidden" name="code" value = "<%=name%>"/> 
    </div>


                <input type="submit" class= "btn btn-image" value="Translate">

                <a href="#search" class="btn btn-default bg-light-gray">Search Text</a>

            </div>
        </div>
          </form>
```

textTranslation.java

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        HttpSession extractedText = request.getSession();
        String imageName = (String) extractedText.getAttribute("text");

        System.out.println("This is "+imageName);
     String name =  request.getParameter("country");
     if(name == null)
     {
         System.out.println("null");
     }
     System.out.println("I selected " +name);
        //String name = "it";
        TranslatorApi translation = new TranslatorApi();

        String outputText =   translation.getTranslate(imageName, name);
        System.out.println("Second"+outputText);
        request.setAttribute("outputText", outputText);


        RequestDispatcher sndValue = request.getRequestDispatcher("/translation.jsp");
        sndValue.forward(request, response);
    }
```

TranslatorApi.java

```
private String apiKey = "AIzaSyCX2O-pteDLJLeMivT47kD9pucEv67QECQ";

    public String getTranslate(String textToBeTranslated, String translateLang)
    {
        Translate translte = null;
        String result = null;
        try
        {
            try {
                translte = new Translate.Builder(com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(), com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance(), null)
                .setApplicationName("OCRProject")
                .build();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        catch(GeneralSecurityException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        Translate.Translations.List list = null;
        try {
            list = translte.new Translations().list(Arrays.asList(textToBeTranslated),translateLang);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        list.setKey(apiKey);
        TranslationsListResponse response = null;
        try {
            response = list.execute();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for (TranslationsResource tr : response.getTranslations()) {
           result = tr.getTranslatedText();
        }
        return result;


    }
```

But if I hard code the code value as

```
String name = "ES";
```

it gives the translated text. As I checked the value passed by dropdown it's not null. Its code value is printed in the console correctly. Does anybody have idea?Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the TranslatorApi class add trim() which remove unnecessary spaces.

```
public String getTranslate(String textToBeTranslated, String translateLang)
{
   translateLang = translateLang.trim();

}
```